# Installing OpenJDK 11 on CentOS using yum

Tags: java, yum, redhat-openjdk

I want to install OpenJDK 11 using yum. However when I check the OpenJDK manual, it says you can use yum to install only up to Java 8. However, for Java 9 onwards it says that you have to download a zip or tar file
(https://openjdk.java.net/install/). How can I install OpenJDK 11 with yum?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason, in short, is because someone has to maintain the packages and put these into the repositories your system is using and verify, that they run stable. For example, the OpenJDK 11 on Debian is still in buster (`testing`) and sid (`unstable`) and therefore not available in any `stable` branch. I guess in CentOS (I am not that familiar with it tbh.) it's the same situation.

Sooner or later you'll have to install software without a manager in any OS, so even if you're saying you're a noob, you'll have to learn that sooner or later. And if you want to use openjdk11 now, you'll have to use either an unofficial repository or install the software by hand, what I'd recommend.

However, here is a guide which is the second hit on Google for `openjdk11 centos`:

```
curl -O https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk11/13/GPL/openjdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
tar zxvf openjdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
mv jdk-11.0.1 /usr/local/

vi /etc/profile.d/jdk11.sh

# create new
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk-11.0.1
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

source /etc/profile.d/jdk11.sh

java -version

openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)
```

Source: https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=jdk11&f=2

Comment: This works for Amazon Linux as of 3/13/2024.

Answer (score 25):

**As of November 2020**

you can achieve this in 2 steps:

1. Install Java 11 using `yum`:

   `yum install java-11-openjdk-devel`
2. Get all the Java configurations available in your machine:

   `alternatives --config java`

   Run the above command, select the version you want to set, I've set `1` here:

   ```
   There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.
   Selection    Command

   -----------------------------------------------
      1           java-11-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.8.10-0.el7_8.x86_64/bin/java)
   *+ 2           java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre/bin/java)

   Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 1
   ```
3. Check `java -version`:

   ```
   openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14 LTS
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.8+10-LTS)
   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.8+10-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
   ```

Java 11 is now set to be used globally.

Comment: I tried this today it does not work.
Maybe they changed

Comment: It worked fine for me today