# Can't install openjdk-11 with yum in container

Tags: java, linux, docker, yum

I am trying to install openjdk-11 inside a container (lambci/lambda:build-python3.6)

Multiple sources claim you can install openjdk 11 by running:

```
yum update

yum install java-11-openjdk-devel
```

However all I get is:

```
No package java-11-openjdk-devel available.
```

And yum search doesn't return anything for jdk 11.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The error is explicit, the package `java-11-openjdk-devel` is not available, the latest version of the `openjdk` package available through the `yum` repos is `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`.

Comment: Here is a link to installation for rhel and centos:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53378483/installing-open-jdk-11-on-centos-using-yum-commands

Answer (score 6):

For "Amazon Linux 2003" AMI, you can use the following command:

```
sudo dnf install java-11-amazon-corretto -y
```

For "Amazon Linux 2" AMI, use

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install java-openjdk11 -y
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Amazon linux 2, Use this

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install java-openjdk11
```